# How to lower levels in json?

Tags: json, vue.js

I have a component of vuejs and my problem is that when I want a roles.name Roles works, but I don't want all JSON.

A example of JSON:

```json
{
  "id_role": 2,
  "name": "Prova",
  "email": "prova@prova.com",
  "email_verified_at": null,
  "created_at": "2021-03-01T09:39:42.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-03-01T09:39:42.000000Z",
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "infomanager",
      "guard_name": "web",
      "created_at": "2021-03-01T09:39:42.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-03-01T09:39:42.000000Z",
      "pivot": {
        "model_id": 4,
        "role_id": 2,
        "model_type": "App\\Models\\User"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is component of vuejs:

```
export default {
    data() {
      return {
        items: [],
        sortBy: '',
        sortDesc: false,
        output: null,
        // Note 'isActive' is left out and will not appear in the rendered table
  

  fields: [
      {
        key: 'name',
        label: 'Nom Usuari',
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'roles.name',
        label: 'Nom Rols',
        sortable: true
      },
      {
        key: 'actions',
        label: 'Accions'
      }
    ],
    
    
  }
},
```

My question is how am I down level, roles.name doesn't work.
Thank you so much!!

Comment: What do you mean exactly when you say down level?

Comment: `roles.name` doesn't work because you got an array with objects. you have to loop through the array first or selected the item via index like `roles[0].name`

Comment: Tank so much Wittgenstein is exactly what i want!! :D.

Comment: Good to hear, Joan.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you want to replace your `roles` array-of-objects to an array which holds only `roles.name` field.

In this case you can use [flatMap](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flatMap) method from [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library.
Assume that your JSON is assigned into a variable called `rolesJson`, it will look like that:

```
let rolesJson = {
  "id_role": 2,
  "name": "Prova",
  "email": "prova@prova.com",
  "email_verified_at": null,
  "created_at": "2021-03-01T09:39:42.000000Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-03-01T09:39:42.000000Z",
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "infomanager",
      "guard_name": "web",
      "created_at": "2021-03-01T09:39:42.000000Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-03-01T09:39:42.000000Z",
      "pivot": {
        "model_id": 4,
        "role_id": 2,
        "model_type": "App\\Models\\User"
      }
    }
  ]
};

// create a new attribute with the flatted roles array 
rolesJson.flatted_roles = _.flatMap(rolesJson.roles, el => {
    return el.name;
});

// remove the original roles array
delete rolesJson.roles;
```